# How do I get this value in an object?

Tags: javascript, object

I need to pull the value out of an object and am not sure how to get to it.

Here's a slimmed down version of my code. Can someone tell me how to get the color?

```
var object = {
 'fruit' : { 
   apple: { 
    goldenDelicious: [
      { color: 'green' }
    ] 
   } 
  }  
 }
```

Comment: I would seriously consider choosing a name other than `object` since `Object` (capitalized) is a built-in JavaScript class.  Try to stay away from such names if possible.

Comment: I suggest to read some documentation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
object.fruit.apple.goldenDelicious[0].color
```